# Robotframework Include Tests which have spaces in it

Tags: robotframework

Suppose my full test name is `Suite 01.test 01.test` how do I pass it with `-t` option of robot tag. I tried putting into quotes but that also did not help it always take `01.test`

Comment: Please show how you tried putting it in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot will ignore spaces and underscores in the names, as well as ignore the case. So, for example, the following are all equivalent:

```
pybot --test Suite01.Test01 ...
pybot --test Suite_01.Test_01 ...
pybot --test suite_01.test01 ...
pybot --test suite01.Test_01 ...
```

And, of course, you can use quotes on the command line if you prefer to use the precise name:

```
$ pybot --test "Suite 01.Test 01" ...
```

All that being said, in my experience spanning a few decades, it's not a good idea to create files with spaces in their names. While every OS allows it, it makes it difficult to work with those files on the command line. You might want to reconsider your decision to allow files with spaces in the name.